# Gradle doesn't compile classes in war project

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, gradle

I have following project setup with Eclipse:

```
project
    build.gradle
    libraries.gradle
    settings.gradle
    ear-project
        build.gradle
    ejb-project
        build.gradle
    war-project
        build.gradle
```

This is build.gradle from root project:

```
apply from: "./libraries.gradle"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "findbugs"

    group = "foo.bar"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

    configurations {
        provided {
            description = "Non-exported compile-time dependencies"
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }

    eclipse {
        classpath {
            plusConfigurations += configurations.provided
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        provided(libraries.javaee)
        provided(libraries.ejb)
        provided(libraries.cdi)
        provided(libraries.jpa)
    }
}
```

ear-project build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "ear"

dependencies {
    deploy project(path: ":ejb")
    deploy project(path: ":war", configuration: "archives")
}
```

ejb-project build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "java"
```

war-project build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "war"
```

After running "gradle build" from command line the .ear-file is generated, but the .war-file contains only non-compiled .java classes. Classes in ejb project are compiled into .class. Why the classes in war-project are not compiled?

Comment: Where are the .java files located in the ejb project?

Comment: Sorry. I meant, where are the .java files located in the war project?

Comment: In war project they are in src/main/webapp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java files must be in `src/main/java`. Not `src/main/webapp`. `src/main/webapp` is the directory where the webapp static assets are located: JSP files, HTML files, JS files, etc.